# Strange Behaviour of java mail sending in JAVAEE and JAVA Project

Tags: java, web-applications, jakarta-mail

Hi I am trying to implement the e-mail sending through my `Web Application`. This is how my `java` `class` is:

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendMail{
    public void sendEmail(String fromEmail, String toEmail,String subject, String message) throws MessagingException{
        System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");        
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);

        Message mailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
        mailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(message+"This E-Mail was sent to you");
        Transport.send(mailMessage);    
    }
}
```

The above code absolutely works fine when I write a `main` method in the class specified above and run it as `java application` or through any other class having `main` method. But it shows `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect] with root cause
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;` when I run my `web application` and calling the `sendMail` method into that class having no `main` method. How do I solve it. Any help much appreciated.
Can anybody give any update on this error `Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Authentication required`. Even if I do password authentication `false` why does it asks for it. I solved all the previous errors and getting the new one like this. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an OS issue. Either localhost's default definition is corrupted (try 127.0.0.1 instead to test this theory) or you have some sort of firewall denying access to port 25.

Comment: @Shloim Then why does it work when I write main method and try to run it as Java Application. I tried the same you said with 127.0.0.1 but it is the same error message I am getting.

Comment: does the main application and the web service run as the same user? Can you test it by creating a Socket object and testing connection to 127.0.0.1 over port 25?

Comment: @Shloim I don't need that as I am doing it with `RestFul Web Services`.

Comment: @Shloim what say if I try this: `props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");`

Comment: @Shloim Hey, when I tried the same it moved forward but giving the exception `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`, so which username and password should I supposed to give?

Comment: `props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");` you *disabled* authentication with this. Could you add `props.put("mail.debug", "true");`, run again and post mail debug output (cleared of passwords)?